How to get 5 equal-sized bins of my data based on a categorical metadata variable?
I have a dataframe with approximately 5000 datapoints and I need to create bins for cross-validation. Additionally, I have a categorical metadata variable with around 1000 unique values. To prevent data leakage, I want to ensure that datapoints sharing the same metadata value are not split across different bins. The bins need to be approximately the same size, and preferably I want to have 5 bins.
I’ve searched for functions to achieve this, but they all seem to cater to numerical variables (e.g., pd.qcut). Since this metadata variable is not used as a predictor in model training, I believe the optbinning package is also not suitable. Does anyone know of a method or package that can help with this?

Don't describe, provide a clear [mre] and the matching expected output, then you can discuss generalization.

Although not ideal, I discovered a workaround for the optbinning package. By assigning random class labels (‘0’ or ‘1’) to my data points, I could use these as targets for optimal binning. Below is the code snippet:

    from optbinning import OptimalBinning
    import numpy as np
    np.random.seed(1)
    optb.fit(df["metadata_class_var"], np.random.choice([0, 1], size=len(df), p=[0.5, 0.5]))
    OptimalBinning(name="metadata_class_var", dtype="categorical", min_bin_size=0.18, max_bin_size=0.22, min_n_bins=5, max_n_bins = 5)



To make sure that datapoints sharing the same categorical metadata value are not split across different bins during cross-validation, you could use this approach.
Start by grouping your data by the metadata variable, to keep all related datapoints together and treating them as a single unit. Then, shuffle these groups to introduce randomness. Once shuffled, you can distribute the groups into bins and combine the groups back into your original DataFrame and assign a bin label to each datapoint.
Here is the code:
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import seaborn as sns
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt
from sklearn.utils import shuffle

# Assuming df is your DataFrame and 'metadata_var' is the categorical metadata column
df = pd.DataFrame({
    'data': np.random.randn(5000),
    'metadata_var': np.random.choice(range(1000), size=5000)
})

# Group by metadata variable
groups = [group for _, group in df.groupby('metadata_var')]

# Shuffle the groups
shuffled_groups = shuffle(groups)

# Assign groups to bins
n_bins = 5
bins = [[] for _ in range(n_bins)]

for i, group in enumerate(shuffled_groups):
    bins[i % n_bins].append(group)

# Combine bins and assign bin numbers
df['bin'] = np.nan
for i, bin_ in enumerate(bins):
    combined_bin = pd.concat(bin_)
    df.loc[combined_bin.index, 'bin'] = i

# Plot the distribution
plt.figure(figsize=(10, 6))
sns.countplot(data=df, x='bin', palette='viridis')
plt.title('Distribution of Datapoints Across Bins')
plt.xlabel('Bin')
plt.ylabel('Count')
plt.show()


